# Is there a safe way to download the java JDK?

Tags: java, ssl, java-7

When I go to the [official website to download the Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html#javasejdk) and attempt to download the JDK, I get an error stating that the SSL certificate for Oracle's download site is invalid.

After some googling, the certificate appears to have never been valid (or been invalid for a very long time).

The error says "This Connection Is Untrusted" in Firefox, and the technical details say:

```
download.oracle.com uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.akamaihd.net, *.akamaihd-staging.net, a248.e.akamai.net, *.akamaized.net, *.akamaized-staging.net
```

In Chrome, the error says "Your connection is not private", with a similar message in the advance info.

After looking for a long time, I can find very little info on this problem via the usual search engines.

Why is the certificate invalid, and what is a good trustworthy way to get the file?

Comment: Re: On Hold  --  I expected this question to be sketchy; however, it does directly involve a tool used specifically for programming (the Java Developer Kit). Also, the issue this question addresses does not occur for the general Java Runtime Environment, this is specific to the JDK. From its high votes and quick vote rate, this question/answer has clearly been valuable. That said, it may have been better asked on Super User. My familiarity with the differences in SE sites is low. I leave the decision to you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The oracle java download site was never designed to use SSL.

The site in this case is only using SSL because of the HTTPSEverywhere browser plugin that I have installed, which is forcing all Oracle domains to use HTTPS when contacted by my browser.

In order to make the download work, I disabled HTTPSEverywhere for the oracle domains. This effectively exposed how the site is actually designed to work (it did not default to SSL), and it allowed the download to proceed without warnings. This indicates that clicking through the warning (no need to disable HTTPSEverwhere in this case) should be okay.

I write this answer here because of the great difficulty of finding any information on this problem via google.

Comment: Congratulations on diagnosing and fixing your problem. And double for documenting it here.

Comment: Thanks! I was mighty frustrated for a bit :)

Comment: Disabling SSL when downloading software is not a solution; everybody on your network, the download provider's network, or any network in between can supply you with malicious code if you're downloading via HTTP.

Comment: It would indeed be good for Oracle to enable SSL for that site.